# What's the result of using "GROUP BY" in mysql to select some column without aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table1 like

```
|id | user_id | amount | group_id|
|1  | 1       | 5      | 1       |
|2  | 2       | 1      | 1       |
|3  | 3       | 3      | 1       |
|4  | 3       | 9      | 2       |
|5  | 1       | 4      | 2       |
```

I just want to `select` the last one for each group_id:

```
|id | user_id | amount | group_id|
|3  | 3       | 3      | 1       |
|5  | 1       | 4      | 2       |
```

There is my SQL:

```
select max(id) , user_id , amount, group_id 
from table1
group by group_id
```

I have no idea whether it work or not.
Does the group by function list the result about the last record for each group ?

Do I have to use table1 join table1 to solve this problem?

Comment: The result you get for `user_id` , `amount` from your query is non-deterministic. Have a look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-handling.html).

Answer (score 5):

It does not work like that. You can get the highest `id` for each group with `max(id)` but the other non-aggregated columns are not predictable to be the ones you want.

You can use a subquery to select the highest `id`s and join that result to the table to get the rest of the columns for those.

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
join
(
  select max(id) as id
  from table1
  group by group_id
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```